# Fastest way to sort tiny lists in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a large number of very small lists I need to sort as quickly as possible. Usually these lists have 2-3 values in them, and the built in sorting methods seem to have too much overhead. Would a simple bubble sort be ok in this situation?

Example, want to sort:

```
[1, 5]
[4, 2]
[3, 7]
...
```

To:

```
[1, 5]
[2, 4]
[3, 7]
...
```

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
def do_something( ilist ):
    ilist = sorted(ilist, reverse = True);
    return ilist;

for i in range(1000000000):
    do_something( [random_num,random_num ] );
```

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the built in functions have too much overhead?

Comment: Python's built-in sort is actually quite fast. It adjusts the algorithm it uses based on the size of the input, and for small lists it'll just end up using insertion sort. It's also implemented in C, so it'll probably be faster than anything you come up with in pure Python. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: Rule: never use bubble sort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python sort() first element of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068315/python-sort-first-element-of-list)

Comment: My code is like 7 times slower when I sort, which seems like a lot since about half of the lists are already sorted. I just need a method to swap the elements if they're out of order, which doesn't seem like an exponential operation

Comment: Have you actually timed your bubble sort against the built-in sort? If so you should add that information to the question. I agree with @dano, the built-in sort is supposed to be optimized for just about every contingency, including very short sequences.

Comment: Is it always two elements?  You say 2-3 above, but say only 2 in a comment below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
If the list of the lists has always 2 element. It's faster to use like `>` operator than using `sorted`.

```
[(i[1], i[0]) if i[0]>i[1] else i for i in lst]
```

Time:

```
lst = [(0, 9),
       (1, 8),
       (2, 7),
       (3, 6),
       (4, 5),
       (5, 4),
       (6, 3),
       (7, 2),
       (8, 1),
       (9, 0)]

%timeit [(i[1], i[0]) if i[0]>i[1] else i for i in lst]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 us per loop

%timeit [sorted(i) for i in lst]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.87 us per loop
```

In your case, you said your list has 2 or 3 elements. So your sort function look like this.

```
def sort_few(lst):
    if len(lst)==2:
        if lst[0] > lst[1]:
            return (lst[1], lst[0])
        else:
            return lst
    else:
        if lst[0] > lst[1]:
            if lst[1] > lst[2]:
                return (lst[2], lst[1], lst[0])
            else:
                return (lst[1], lst[2], lst[0])
        elif lst[1] > lst[2]:
            if lst[2] > lst[0]:
                return (lst[0], lst[2], lst[1])
            else:
                return (lst[2], lst[0], lst[1])
        elif lst[2] > lst[0]:
            if lst[0] > lst[1]:
                return (lst[1], lst[0], lst[2])
            else:
                return lst
```

Time:

```
lst = [(1, 2, 3),
       (1, 3, 2),
       (2, 1, 3),
       (2, 3, 1),
       (3, 1, 2),
       (3, 2, 1),
       (1, 2, 3),
       (1, 3, 2),
       (2, 1, 3),
       (2, 3, 1),
       (3, 1, 2),
       (3, 2, 1)]


%timeit [sort_few(i) for i in lst]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.3 us per loop

%timeit [sorted(i) for i in lst]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.32 us per loop
```

So it's faster to use `sort_few` than `sorted` if there are a 2 or 3 element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) is pretty efficient:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 5], [4, 2], [3, 7]]
>>> sorted_lol = [sorted(sub_list) for sub_list in list_of_lists]
>>> sorted_lol
[[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not sublists. It's a function that sorts a list of size 2... 100000000 times or however many are needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
values = [{1, 5},{4, 2},{3, 7}]
print(sorted(values))
```

Result:

```
[set([1, 5]), set([2, 4]), set([3, 7])]
```

Comment: He wants to sort sub-lists, and sets are unordered, so I don't see how this answers his question at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only two elements:

```
f = lambda x: x if x[0] < x[1] else [x[1],x[0]]
```

then

```
x = [5,4]
f(x)
```

This would return '[4,5]'

```
x = [4,5]
f(x)
```

Also returns [4,5]

If it's more than two this doesn't work, though you could special case 3.  This just doing a compare and swap instead of calling a full sort function.