# Organizing of Dynamic Lists of Lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm sorry if this has been answered (I looked and did not find anything.)  Please let me know and I will delete immediately.

I am writing a program that makes an API call which returns a multiple lists of different length depending on the call *(e.g. facebook API call.  Enter the persons name and a list of pictures is returned and each picture has a list of of who "liked" each photo.  I want to store a list of a list of these "likes").*

```
#Import urllib for API request
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
#First I have a function that takes two arguments, first and last name
#Function will return a list of all photos the person has been tagged in facebook
def id_list_generator(first,last):
    #Please note I don't actually know facebook API, this part wil not be reproducible
    pic_id_request = urllib.request.open('www.facebook.com/pics/id/term={first}+{last}[person]')
    pic_id_list = pic_id_request.read()
    for i in pic_id_list:
       id_list.append(i)
  return(id_list)
#Now, for each ID of a picture, I will generate a list of people who "liked" that picture.
#This is where I have trouble.  I don't know how to store these list of lists.
for i in id_list:
    pic_list = urllib.request.open('www.facebook.com/pics/id/like/term={i}[likes]')
    print pic_list
```

This would print multiple lists of "likes" for each picture the person was tagged in:

```
foo, bar
bar, baz
baz, foo, qux
norf
```

I don't really know how to store these honestly.

I was thinking of using a list that would look like this after appending:

```
foo = [["foo", "bar"], ["bar","baz"],["baz","foo","qux"],["norf"]]
```

But really I'm not sure what type of storage to use in this case.  I thought of using a dictionary of a dictionary, but I don't know if the key can be iterable.  I feel like there is a simple answer to this that I am missing.

Comment: Your example is a little too abstract to make much sense. Could you give an example of some sort of realistic input data and give another example of your required output. It won't hurt to show anything you've tried yourself either.

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried to clarify more :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could have a list of dictionaries:

Here's an example:

```
facebook_likes = [{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "image_link": "link",
    "likes": ["foo"]
}, {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "image_link": "link",
    "likes": ["foo", "bar"]
}]

for like in facebook_likes:
    print like
    print like["likes"]
    print like["likes"][0]
```

You should also look into JSON objects.
Its one of the standard response objects that you get after making API calls.
Fortunately, its very simple to transform a Python dict into a JSON object and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort by the first element in each list, Python does that by default for 2D lists. Refer to this thread: [Python sort() first element of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068315/python-sort-first-element-of-list)