# How to order a list of lists by the first value

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that looks like this

```
l1 = [[1,'steve'],[4,'jane'],[3,'frank'],[2,'kim']]
```

and I want to order them by the first number

how would i go about this, thank you

Comment: `.sort` orders by the first element by default so you should be able to say `l1.sort()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a list of lists by a specific index of the inner list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python sort() first element of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068315/python-sort-first-element-of-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l1.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Should do the trick make sure you have the int() cast as you can run into further errors with larger numbers because the integers are lexicographically compared. i.e., `'5'` will be larger than `'20'`

Comment: A simple `l1.sort()` will do the trick. as far as casting to int, the example dat shows all as being int. I don't think it's needed.

Answer (score 11):

By default, `sorted` will use the first element:

```
>>> l1 = [[1,'steve'],[4,'jane'],[3,'frank'],[2,'kim']]
>>> sorted(l1)
[[1, 'steve'], [2, 'kim'], [3, 'frank'], [4, 'jane']]
```

As noted in the comments, `l1.sort()` will sort the original list in place, and is a better option if you don't need to preserve the original order.

This is the way the comparison operators work in Python:

```
>>> [1, 'something'] < [2, 'something']
True
```

Note that if the first element compares as equal, it will compare the second element, and so on:

```
>>> [1, 1, 1] < [1, 1, 2]
True
```

This means that two names with the same number would be sorted (lexicographically) by the string, not in place:

```
>>> sorted([[1, 'mike'], [1, 'bob']])
[[1, 'bob'], [1, 'mike']]
```

Comment: It actually uses every element if needed. If 2 elements have the same first element, sorted will compare the 2nd element. see `[[1, 2], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 1], [2, 0]]`

Comment: It's important to note that `sorted(l1)` returns a sorted copy whereas `l1.sort()` sorts in place. Unless the OP needs th preserve the original order, I would recommend against using `sorted()` over `.sort()`.

Answer (score 4):

Python sort will compare the lists with the first element by default. If they're the same, it will continue with the second element, and so on.

so

```
l1.sort()
```

will do.

But if you really just want to sort by first value and nothing else :

```
sorted(l1, key=lambda id_and_name: id_and_name[0])
#=> [[1, 'steve'], [2, 'kim'], [3, 'frank'], [4, 'jane']]
```

Comment: No need for `sorted` in your second example: `l1.sort(key=lambda id_and_name: id_and_name[0])`

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter
l1 = [[1,'steve'],[4,'jane'],[3,'frank'],[2,'kim']]
l1 = sorted(l1, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Comment: It's important to note that `sorted(l1)` returns a sorted copy whereas `l1.sort()` sorts in place. Unless the OP needs th preserve the original order, I would recommend against using `sorted()` over `.sort()`. Nice use of `itemgetter`, but a simple `l1.sort()` will do the trick.

Comment: Please provide some explanation why this answer solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [[1,'steve'],[4,'jane'],[3,'frank'],[2,'kim']]
ol = sorted(l1, key=lambda key_value: key_value[0])

print (ol)
```

output:

```
[[1, 'steve'], [2, 'kim'], [3, 'frank'], [4, 'jane']]
```

Comment: It's important to note that `sorted(l1)` returns a sorted copy whereas `l1.sort()` sorts in place. Unless the OP needs th preserve the original order, I would recommend against using `sorted()` over `.sort()`.

Comment: But sorted(l1) would return : none

Comment: `l1.sort(key=lambda key_value: key_value[0])` returns `None`, but you wouldn't need to assign the result to anything.  Just use `l1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
l1 = [[1,'steve'],[4,'jane'],[3,'frank'],[2,'kim']]
sorted_l1 = sorted(l1, key=lambda item: item[0])  # Or simply sorted(l1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> sorted_l1
[[1, 'steve'], [2, 'kim'], [3, 'frank'], [4, 'jane']]
```

If you want to update the same list (to be sorted), try the following:

```
>>> l1.sort(key=lambda item: item[0])  # Or simply l1.sort()
>>> l1
[[1, 'steve'], [2, 'kim'], [3, 'frank'], [4, 'jane']]
```